# PySpark Dataframe - Iterate over window partition by

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's assume that we have data like this(sorted by time) and created the dummy column for the classes in Pyspark dataframe:

```
ID  class   e_TYPE_B    e_TYPE_C    e_TYPE_L    e_TYPE_A    e_TYPE_E    e_TYPE_G
1   G           0           0           0           0           0           1
1   B           1           0           0           0           0           0
1   B           1           0           0           0           0           0
2   E           0           0           0           0           1           0
2   E           0           0           0           0           1           0
2   C           0           1           0           0           0           0
2   C           0           1           0           0           0           0
2   E           0           0           0           0           1           0
2   E           0           0           0           0           1           0
3   L           0           0           1           0           0           0
3   L           0           0           1           0           0           0
3   B           1           0           0           0           0           0
3   E           0           0           0           0           1           0
4   A           0           0           0           1           0           0
4   A           0           0           0           1           0           0
5   B           1           0           0           0           0           0
5   B           1           0           0           0           0           0
5   A           0           0           0           1           0           0
5   A           0           0           0           1           0           0
```

Now, I am trying to findout the count of ID moving from one class to another.It can be consecutive or may have some other classes in between. The relation should be created for each class from top to bottom on ID basis.

For Example,

- ID 1 goes from G to B then 1 should be added to G to B counter,
- ID 2 goes from E to C then 1 should be added to E to C counter,
- ID 2 goes from C to E then 1 should be added to C to E counter,
- ID 3 goes from L to B then 1 should be added to L to B counter,
- ID 3 goes from B to E then 1 should be added to B to E counter,
- Also ID 3 goes from L to E then 1 should be added to L to E counter,
- ID 4 have only one class so it should be discarded

I thought of using Window operation which should partition on ID, but how to iterate the partition to calculate the count of above class relation is that i am struggling on.

Please provide the solution/code snippet for this.

Thanks.

Comment: goupBy ID and use  collect_list on class. Then use a UDF to iterate over the possible combinations.

Comment: thanks mikeL... can you please help me with UDF?

Comment: You should post what your desired output looks like.